# Async OnCommand of a Button in an ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I try to make onCommand function of a LinkButton asynchronous.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="..." runat="server" OnCommand="FooCommand" </asp>

protected async void FooCommand(object source, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    var result = await somethingAsync();
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(...., string.Format("<script...{0}....</script>", msg)
}
```

Is it OK to use async void in this context? Should I use ConfigureAwait(false) after the async call?

Comment: I wouldn't go into the details of why web form is a horrible technology. But keep in mind that http is client/server thing, so maybe you would do something like an API call after the operation is done instead of await?

Comment: WebForms is a wonderfull technology but, as anything else in the universe, you must have a minimum understanding of it to be able to use it correctly. That being said, ASP.NET has always had asynchronous capabilities and in WebForms is getting easier and easier. Take a look at my ["async-await and ASP.NET" curation](https://curah.microsoft.com/44400/async-and-aspnet). You might find some usefull articles in there.

Comment: @PauloMorgado your link is broken... It would have been far more useful to simply submit an answer to the question.

Comment: @Steve you think people always have a choice?